# how should rails nested resources path look?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have a resource nested in another:

```
resource :users do
  resource :posts
end
```

The official guide says I should have this url:

```
/users/:id/posts/:id
```

To `show` `update` `edit` or `delete` the posts. But in fact I have:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 > app.users_posts_path(1,2)
=> "/users/posts.1?=2"
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Please say where exactly in which `guide` you are seeing that.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: `/users/:id/posts` (note the plural on posts) implies all posts for that user but if you want to show/edit/update/delete the post then it's /user/:id/post/:id

Comment: an edge case might be 'delete_all' for deleting all posts but I am actually not sure off-the-bat how that will relate to the routes issues.

Comment: But I HAVE `/users/posts.:id=:id`, not `/user/:id/post/:id` or something other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using standard plural routes, not singular, so use `resources` instead of `resource`:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to see your routes? in you console type:

```
$ bundle exec rake routes
```

Usually user_posts_path is the GET request for listing items (are you sure that in your route name user is plural?), so you just need to provide the first parameter that represents your :id, related to users.